# how to provide info according to the logged in user in php

Tags: php, mysql

could anyone help me please? I am writing a program where a patient takes an appointment to meet a doctor and after the appoints being taken, that patient will be on "Pending" status until only the doctor that was selected by the patient sees the patient's record and approves it. I tried so many attempts but it keeps dispaying. I have down here a screenshot to illustrate what I meant. Im currently logged in as " **Sandeep H S**" so i only want him to see appointments taken by patients with him
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKny0.png)

```
<div class="box-body">
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Patient</th>
<th>Contact</th>
<th>Date & Heure de Rendez-vous</th>
<th>Département</th>
<th>Docteur</th>
<th>Raisons</th>
<th>Statut</th>
<th>Action</th>


</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
$sql ="SELECT * FROM appointment WHERE (status='En Attente' OR status='Inactive')";
if(isset($_SESSION[patientid]))
{
$sql  = $sql . " AND patientid='$_SESSION[patientid]'";
}
$qsql = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($rs = mysqli_fetch_array($qsql))
{
$sqlpat = "SELECT * FROM patient WHERE patientid='$rs[patientid]'";
$qsqlpat = mysqli_query($con,$sqlpat);
$rspat = mysqli_fetch_array($qsqlpat);


$sqldept = "SELECT * FROM department WHERE departmentid='$rs[departmentid]'";
$qsqldept = mysqli_query($con,$sqldept);
$rsdept = mysqli_fetch_array($qsqldept);

$sqldoc= "SELECT * FROM doctor WHERE doctorid='$rs[doctorid]'";
$qsqldoc = mysqli_query($con,$sqldoc);
$rsdoc = mysqli_fetch_array($qsqldoc);
echo "<tr>

<td>&nbsp;$rspat[patientname] $rspat[patientfn]</td>
<td>&nbsp;$rspat[mobileno]</td>
<td>&nbsp;" . date("d-M-Y",strtotime($rs[appointmentdate])) . " &nbsp; " . date("H:i",strtotime($rs[appointmenttime])) . "</td>
<td>&nbsp;$rsdept[departmentname]</td>
<td>&nbsp;$rsdoc[doctorname]</td>
<td>&nbsp;$rs[app_reason]</td>
<td>&nbsp;$rs[status]</td>
<td><div align='center'>";
if($rs[status] != "Approved")
{
if(!(isset($_SESSION[patientid])))
{
echo "<a href='appointmentapproval.php?editid=$rs[appointmentid]&patientid=$rs[patientid]'>Approuver</a><hr>";
}
echo "  <a href='viewappointmentpending.php'>Supprimer</a>";
}
else
{
echo "<a href='patientreport.php?patientid=$rs[patientid]&appointmentid=$rs[appointmentid]'>Voir Rapport</a>";
}
echo "</center></td></tr>";
}
?>

</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: What error are you receiving? ... Also, your code as written will run a query whether `patientid` is in session or not. Perhaps put `patientid` in quotes, as you should. However, even then, the query will still run regardless.

Comment: I am not receiving any error, just that i want only patients that have appointment with a specific doctor that they selected to display but instead it also displays appointments with other doctors like on the image i added to the post

Comment: Have a look at the rest of my comment.

Comment: I think the problem is more on how to select the doctor who is currently logged in

Comment: More than one problem, yes. Helps to fix the ones I pointed out tho.

Comment: Medical software that deals with doctors. patients and their data, fall under HIPPA laws that have very strict requirements. Not for nothing, (and no offense intended) but if you're asking questions like this, its very unlikely that your app will adhere to these laws. Please see [HIPAA Compliance and Software Development](https://www.accountablehq.com/post/hipaa-and-software-development)

Comment: Your `AND` shouldn't be `patientid`, it should be `doctor_id` or whatever field you have for the logged in doctor. Also @WesleySmith is right. .... But if this is just a practice exercise to learn the ropes, then look into SQL prepared statements to make your code more readable; has the side effect of being more secure.

Answer (score 0):

You say you are "logged in as" some doctor or other. But the code you showed us doesn't seem to take any notice of that. Do you have a session variable like `$_SESSION[doctorid]` showing that you're logged in?

Can you select the appointments based on that doctor's id in your first SELECT? That should show you the desired appointments.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out there are a number of mistakes with your code which will throw `notices|warnings|errors` even if in practice it *works*.

The key reason behind you `selecting` results for multiple `doctors` however appears to be that you never actually specify (in your `WHERE` clauses) that you only want results from the `doctor` that is currently logged on.

Rather you get a `$_SESSION` variable for a `patient` instead - which makes no sense - and limit your appointments to that `patient`.

It seems to me that you would do better to run one query with `JOINs` to capture all of the data that you need and loop through the result set without the need of additional `SELECT` statements...

### Suggested Code

**mysqli**

```
$sql = "
    SELECT
        appointment.app_reason, appointment.appointmentdate, appointment.appointmentid, appointment.appointmenttime, appointment.status,
        department.departmentname,
        doctor.doctorname,
        patient.mobileno, patient.patientfn, patient.patientname

    FROM appointment
        JOIN department ON department.departmentid = appointment.departmentid
        JOIN doctor ON doctor.doctorid = appointment.doctorid
        JOIN patient ON patient.patientid = appointment.patientid

    WHERE (status='En Attente' OR status='Inactive')
        AND appointment.doctorid = ?
";

$query = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$query->bind_param("i", $_SESSION["doctorid"]); // Or wherever you store the "logged in" doctor's id

$query->execute();
$query->store_result();
$query->bind_result($app_reason, $appointmentdate, $appointmentid, $appointmenttime, $status, $departmentname, $doctorname, $mobileno, $patientfn, $patientname);

while($query->fetch()){

    // It's good practice not to have these functions embedded in your string
    $date = date("d-M-Y",strtotime($appointmentdate));
    $time = date("H:i",strtotime($appointmenttime));

    echo "<tr>
        <td>&nbsp;{$patientname} {$patientfn}</td>
        <td>&nbsp;{$mobileno}</td>
        <td>&nbsp;{$date}&nbsp;{$time}</td>
        <td>&nbsp;{$departmentname}</td>
        <td>&nbsp;{$doctorname}</td>
        <td>&nbsp;{$app_reason}</td>
        <td>&nbsp;{$status}</td>
        <td><div align='center'>";

    if($status != "Approved"){
        if(!(isset($patientid))){
            echo "<a href='appointmentapproval.php?editid={$appointmentid}&patientid={$patientid}'>Approuver</a><hr>";
        }
        echo "  <a href='viewappointmentpending.php'>Supprimer</a>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<a href='patientreport.php?patientid={$patientid}&appointmentid={$appointmentid}'>Voir Rapport</a>";
    }
    echo "</center></td></tr>";
}
```

**PDO**

```
$sql = "
    SELECT
        appointment.app_reason, appointment.appointmentdate, appointment.appointmentid, appointment.appointmenttime, appointment.status,
        department.departmentname,
        doctor.doctorname,
        patient.mobileno, patient.patientfn, patient.patientname

    FROM appointment
        JOIN department ON department.departmentid = appointment.departmentid
        JOIN doctor ON doctor.doctorid = appointment.doctorid
        JOIN patient ON patient.patientid = appointment.patientid

    WHERE (status='En Attente' OR status='Inactive')
        AND appointment.doctorid = ?
";

$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->execute([$_SESSION["doctorid"]]); // Or wherever you store the "logged in" doctor's id

while($appointment=$query->fetchObject()){ // Alternative: $appointment=$query->fetch(); and use as array, e.g. $appointment["patientname"]

    // It's good practice not to have these functions embedded in your string
    $date = date("d-M-Y",strtotime($appointmentdate));
    $time = date("H:i",strtotime($appointmenttime));

    echo "<tr>
        <td>&nbsp;{$appointment->patientname} {$appointment->patientfn}</td>
        <td>&nbsp;{$appointment->mobileno}</td>
        <td>&nbsp;{$appointment->date}&nbsp;{$appointment->time}</td>
        <td>&nbsp;{$appointment->departmentname}</td>
        <td>&nbsp;{$appointment->doctorname}</td>
        <td>&nbsp;{$appointment->app_reason}</td>
        <td>&nbsp;{$appointment->status}</td>
        <td><div align='center'>";

    if($status != "Approved"){
        if(!(isset($patientid))){
            echo "<a href='appointmentapproval.php?editid={$appointment->appointmentid}&patientid={$appointment->patientid}'>Approuver</a><hr>";
        }
        echo "  <a href='viewappointmentpending.php'>Supprimer</a>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<a href='patientreport.php?patientid={$appointment->patientid}&appointmentid={$appointment->appointmentid}'>Voir Rapport</a>";
    }
    echo "</center></td></tr>";
}
```